# Compatibility with Phantomjs Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, selenium, phantomjs

Friends.

I have a small doubt regarding Phantomjs and Angularjs because I'm trying to do an Automated Test Using Phantomjs but has errors related to Jquery and Angularjs.

Following following error:

`page.onError - msg: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: angular`

`page.onError - msg: ReferenceError: Can't find variable: jQuery`

Any Solution?

Comment: Are you using Karma? How do you add your tests files? Are you loading jQuery and AngularJS before your app scripts?

Answer (score 0):

try adding the angular and jquery dependency plugin once again using bower or npm. And mention their relative path into your karma task in your taskrunner file.